# Couchdb Attachment name '_design/modify' starts with prohibited character '_'

Tags: couchdb, insert-update

I want to create a new design document into my couch database.

When I try to `PUT` a new `Update Handler` :

```
http://myCouchDbServer/myDatabaseName/db/_design/modify
```

with the following body:

```
{
    "_id": "_design/modify",
    "updates": {
        "modifyinplace": "function (doc, req) { var fields = JSON.parse(req.body); for (var i in fields) { doc[i] = fields[i] } var resp = eval(uneval(doc)); delete resp._revisions; return [doc, toJSON(resp)]; }"
     }
}
```

It returns the response:`400 Bad Request`

```
{
   "error": "bad_request",
   "reason": "Attachment name '_design/modify' starts with prohibited character '_'"
}
```

Am I in the right road?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `/db` from the `URL`. You've already included the database name in the `URL`.